# Magic Square Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, puzzle

Having problems with my code and cannot seem to fix it or know where i have gone wrong. any help will be appreciated.

it runs but doesn't go any further than the user inputting the text file name.

it is supposed to read the user input and from that read a text file and declare whether it is a magic puzzle or not, i wanted this to read 5x5 as well but i'm a bit lost on how to do it

```
column = 0
row = 0
data = []
def main():

    file = input("Enter filename :")
    while True:
        try:
            f = open(file+".txt","r")
            break
        except:
            file = input("Enter filename :")


        for line in f.readline():
            numbers = line.split(' ')
            cube = [int(x) for x in numbers]
            is_magic(x)


def is_magic(x):

    if not dupe(x) and check_sum(x):        
        print ('Valid')

    else:        
        print ('Invalid')


def dupe(x):


    if len(x) == len(set(x)):        
        return False
    return True



def check_sum(x):


    if vertical_check(x) and horizontal_check(x) and diagonal_check(x):
        return True
    return False


def vertical_check(x):

    if sum(x[0:9:3]) == sum(x[1:9:3]) == sum(x[2:9:3]) == 15:      
        return True    
    return False


def horizontal_check(x):

    if sum(cube[0:3]) == sum(cube[3:6]) == sum(cube[6:9]) == 15:      
        return True    
    return False


def diagonal_check(x):

    if sum(cube[0:9:4]) == sum(cube[2:7:2]) == 15:      
        return True    
    return False

def writeFile(x):
    f = open("VALID_"+x+".txt","w")
    text = ""
    for a in data:

        for x in a:
            text = text+str(x)+" "
        text = text+"\n"

    f.write(text)
    f.close()
    return

main()
'''
```

txt file 3x3

```
2 9 4

7 5 3

6 1 8
```

Comment: Be careful about using a bare `except` like that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your questions after they've been answered.

Answer (score 1):

the reason for the program being stuck is the `break` statement after opening the file. This break statement will exit the while loop, so the rest of the code will not be executed.

```
            f = open(file+".txt","r")
            break   # <<<< remove this
```

Answer (score 1):

The break statement inside while True makes you break the loop.

```
while True:
try:
    f = open(file+".txt","r")
    break
```